# How to bind this json and read specific key value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have below json which I would like to read it in a list. below are the classes and model defined and the code by which I am trying to read. I am getting null value on binding. I am not sure how should i achieve this. So for example if I have multiple rules, I would like to read each one based on the condition passed. Please see my last sample code for better understanding.

Sample Json:

```
{"TableStorageRule": { "Rules": [ {
    "Name": "filterRule1",
    "DataFilter":
    {
      "DataSetType": "Settings1"

    },
    "TableSettings":
    {
      "AzureTable": {
        "Account": "account1",
        "Table": "table1",
        "Key": "key1"
      },
      "SchemaBaseUri": "https://test.web.core.windows.net/"
    }

  },
  {
    "Name": "filterRule2",
    "DataFilter":
    {
      "DataSetType": "Settings2"

    },
    "TableSettings":
    {
      "AzureTable": {
        "Account": "account2",
        "Table": "table2",
        "Key": "key2"
      },
      "SchemaBaseUri": "https://test2.web.core.windows.net/"
    }

  }
  
  
]  }}
```

Model and Code:

```
public class TableStoreSettings
{
    public class AzureTableSettings
    {
        public string Account { get; set; }
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public string Table { get; set; }
    }

    public AzureTableSettings AzureTable { get; set; }

    public Uri SchemaBaseUri { get; set; }
}

public class TableStorageRule
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public TwisterDataFilter DataFilter { get; set; }
    public TableStoreSettings TableSettings { get; set; }
}

public class TableStorageConfiguration
{
    public IEnumerable<TableStorageRule> Rules { get; set; } = new List<TableStorageRule>();
}
```

code by which I am trying to read:

```
 var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Path.Combine(Root))
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false);

        var config = builder.Build();
        
        var tableStorageOutput = new TableStorageRule();            
        config.GetSection("TableStorageRule").Bind(tableStorageOutput);
        var nameOfFilter = tableStorageOutput.Name;

        if (tableStorageOutput.Name == "filterRule1")
        {
            var accountname = tableStorageOutput.TableSettings.AzureTable.Account;
        }
```

on above I only get first filtername1 , i dont get other filternames and so on...though on GetSection() i see all the values in quick watch.

Comment: looks like inside "TableStorageRule" json you have "Rules", which is an array of TableStorageRule type. You are missing this while binding.

Comment: i thought so.. can you specify, how can i fix that?

Answer (score 1):

this is correct models from your JSON file :

```
public class DataFilter    {
    public string DataSetType { get; set; } 
}

public class AzureTable    {
    public string Account { get; set; } 
    public string Table { get; set; } 
    public string Key { get; set; } 
}

public class TableSettings    {
    public AzureTable AzureTable { get; set; } 
    public string SchemaBaseUri { get; set; } 
}

public class Rule    {
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public DataFilter DataFilter { get; set; } 
    public TableSettings TableSettings { get; set; } 
}

public class TableStorageRule    {
    public List<Rule> Rules { get; set; } 
}

public class Root    {
    public TableStorageRule TableStorageRule { get; set; } 
}
```

for test you can read your JSON file and get values (maybe change models solve your problem in your code):

```
string json = File.ReadAllText(jsonFilePath);
Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
```

Comment: The way i am doing is .net core way of doing it..and I am unable to fix the issue though I know where I am doing the mistake. I would like to go with my original way

Comment: As I mentioned for the test, you can read the file with my code. Moreover, your model is not matched with the JSON file.